# Does Taylor Expansion for $f(x+h)$ work for $f(x+h)g(x+h)$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

Hi I stumbled along the derivation for the taylor expansion for $$f(x+h)$$
[How is the Taylor expansion for $f(x + h)$ derived?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254792/how-is-the-taylor-expansion-for-fx-h-derived)

And I was wondering whether it works the same as $$f(x+h)g(x+h)$$

For example, if we had $$(x+h)\cos(x+h)$$

Would the taylor expansion be something like this

$$(x+h)\cos(x+h) = x\cos(x) + h(\cos(x)-x\sin(x)) + \frac{h^2}{2}(-2\sin(x)-x\cos(x)) +O(h^3)$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplying Taylor series and composition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106649/multiplying-taylor-series-and-composition). For common questions, check to see if your question has already been answered using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz).

Comment: Just consider function $\phi = f \cdot g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $k(x)=f(x)g(x)$. Then $k(x+h)=f(x+h)g(x+h)$ and you just apply the general procedure of expanding a function into its Taylor series:
$$k(x+h)=k(x)+hk'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}k''(x)+O(h^3)$$
Writing out the derivatives of $k$ in terms of $f,g$, we have
$$f(x+h)g(x+h)=f(x)g(x)+h(f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x))+\frac{h^2}{2}(f''(x)g(x)+2g'(x)f'(x)+f(x)g''(x))+O(h^3)$$
On the other hand, you could also multiply the Taylor expansions directly:
$$(f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+O(h^3))(g(x)+hg'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}g''(x)+O(h^3))$$
and collecting the powers of $h$ you get exactly the same expansion
as above, where $O(h^3)$ will absorb all the powers of $h$ higher than $2$.

The first method is of course easier. The second one shows that the first is equivalent to multiplying the separate series.

Comment: Please avoid answering duplicate questions.

Comment: Please file in your complaints in three copies.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @uniquesolution Cheers for answer! Confirms my intuition :). I also check numerically that this works too with desmos.